# Implementing custom module-resolution logic using Compiler API

Tags: typescript, module, typescript-compiler-api

I need to implement some custom module-resolution logic for some TypeScript code that I have. I'm pretty new to TypeScript so the answer to this may be obvious. I've been looking at the Compiler API, specifically the section on [customizing module resolution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#customizing-module-resolution). I can see that I can provide an implementation for `resolveModuleNames`. What's not clear to me is how I can do that.

The only thing I'm trying to do is to implement this custom resolution logic, but use everything else as-is. Looking at the TypeScript compiler source, I see that it parses the commandline options and immediately spins up a compiler with `CompilerHost` that it creates. But it's not clear to me how I can hook into this or replace this `CompilerHost` instance.

Would I have to duplicate all this logic? The examples in the documentation seem to instantiate a compiler from scratch, and I can't find any examples where I can simply enhance the TypeScript compiler I am using.

Comment: AFAIK there are no hooks in `tsc` for that, you have to use API from beginning to end and you have to write all the glue code that invokes command line and/or `tsconfig.json` parsing, creates compiler and so on.

Comment: @artem That's unfortunate. But the API is still in beta so they may add this feature eventually.

Comment: Based on a [precedent with custom output transformer API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14419#issuecomment-283721389), I'd say it's unlikely.

Comment: See https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript for custom transformers.